# Variables in Locals and Expressions not accessible in QT Creator

Tags: c++, debugging, qt-creator

If I try to debug my C++ program in QT Creator the Locals and Expressions window shows me the variables in the program. However all the values show "< not accessible >".

Screenshot:

[image]

How do I get the values to show? I can print the values out with cout so I know they are initialized.

Edit: It seems like it only applies to strings

Specs/other:

- Windows 8, 64bit
- QT 5.2.0
- MinGW 32bit, I think 4.8
- QT Creator 3.0.0

Comment: Maybe you don't have (or don't have used) the debug version of the Qt libraries when linking?

Comment: I'm very new to this. How do I check if I have used that?

Answer (score 12):

Try to remove the checkmark at Tools/Options/Debugger/GDB/Load system GDB pretty printers, and see whether this makes a difference.

Comment: This is the answer. Also for Qt-specific types the debug information files need to be added for more in-depth debugging into the Qt library itself.

Answer (score 7):

Solved:

> For composite types (std::string and other classes) it doesn’t
>   automatically convert to some default type (e.g. std::string to
>   char*); so what you need to do it right-click on a value, then select
>   the submenu Change local display format-> Raw structure, and then keep
>   opening the symbol until you get something meaningful (when possible).
>   E.g. for std::string, after you change to “Raw structure”, you get
>   your actual string (by clicking the “+” sign to the left of your
>   symbol) in: _M_dataplus->_M_p
>
> Note that you can “Change local display format” for one symbol (the
>   one you selected) or for all symbols of that type (e.g. you select a
>   std::string, then all std::strings change to Raw structure)

From this link: http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/36121/

Credit goes to Gyll.