# How to solve Qt Creators variable-"<not accessible>" behavior?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, fedora

I have the same problem as described in [Variables in Locals and Expressions not accessible in QT Creator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610186/variables-in-locals-and-expressions-not-accessible-in-qt-creator) but I want to find a way how to "repair" Qt Creator showing default composite types like std::string in the debugging window again.

I've updated from Creator 2.8 to 3.0 via a dist upgrade (fedora 18=>20) and I know things can go wrong there but I really want to avoid re-installing the whole OS just for Qt Creator.

Is there any way to make the Creator more verbose or does it write to a log file?

Is Qt Creator 3.0 known to show nice values for composite types anyway?

What components can I check and how?

Comment: use eclipse-cdt as debugger.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Unfortunately it's only a workaround (but I will write more as soon as possible) but [this](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/36766) post pointed me to just **disable "Load system GDB pretty printers"** in *Tools->Options->Debugger->GDB*

This behavior is a [filed bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-11284) in QtCreator 3.0

seems to work for me now!

EDIT: Although the bug tracker for QtCreator 3.0 says the bug has been fixed, the bug actually persists in later versions - at least as of v3.1.2 . Fortunately the same suggested workaround applies.

Comment: In my case with QT Creator 3.1.2, the issue remained for strings. Right click on a variable name and choosing `Change local display format-> Raw structure` as described [here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/35538/qt-creator-debugging-the-values-of-all-string-variables-in-locals-and-expressions-are-not-accessible/2) solved the problem.

Comment: 4.5.1 here (Win10) - still the same issue!

Comment: this behavior still persists in Qt Creator v4.7.0

Answer (score 4):

For windows users updated to Qt 5.11.2 and who using CDB.

On installer (Qt Maintenance tool) make sure the 'Qt -> Qt 5.11.2 -> Qt Debug Information Files' is checked. (There was no such option in previous releases).

Comment: -1 The OP asks for standard C++ types such as `std::string`. The Qt debug information files are 1)huge (several gigabytes!) in terms of disk space and 2)required for debugging the actual Qt library in depth (if we take the OP's `std::string` in this case we are talking about `QString`).

Answer (score 0):

Fedora uses rpm for package management - use it. Reinstallation of the entire OS would be pointless, it's [cargo cult IT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming). If you run `rpm -Va`, you can verify if the packages have not been corrupted, that's all you really need.

Creator has Qt-version-specific debugging helpers, perhaps they don't extend to C++ standard library.

To make sure that the whatever helpers are available are built, go to *Preferences -> Build&Run -> Qt Versions*. For each Qt version, go to the details of the *Helpers* pane, and click *[Build All]*.

Comment: Well - my problem is I **used** the package management and now I'm looking for a way how to solve the problems that came with the dist upgrade **without** the "cargo cult IT" (reinstalling).

Comment: btw. `rpm -Va` (is this what you meant?) on all packages qt-creator or qt-devel depend on returned no result.

Comment: @frans Good, that means those packages are intact. Build the debugging helpers and that's all there's to be done. As I've said, the debugging helpers are there for Qt types only IIRC, C++ library types should be supported by the debugger itself, you'd hope.