# QtCreator / GDB debugger: not accessible, or `this` object not shown

Tags: c++, gdb, qt-creator

In my `main()`, I have some variable (`reader`) on the stack, which is of type `OggReader` (some own `struct`/`class`). This variable is shown as `<not accessible>` in the Qt Creator / GDB debugger:

[image: screen1]

Then, I call some function on this class, so that `this` should point to this `reader` object. But Qt Creator / GDB does not show the content of `this`:

[image: screen2]
[image: screen3]

Why? How can I fix this?

This is Qt Creator 4.0.2 on Ubuntu 16.04.
I use g++ 5.4.0 with options `-g -O0 -g3 -ggdb`.
I use gdb 7.11.1.

The `OggReader` class:

```
struct OggReader {
    Page buffer_page_;
    std::map<uint32_t, VorbisStream> streams_;
    size_t packet_counts_;
    std::shared_ptr<IReader> reader_;
    ParseCallbacks& callbacks_;

    OggReader(ParseCallbacks& callbacks) : packet_counts_(0), callbacks_(callbacks) {}

    ...
};
```

`Page`:

```
struct Page {
    PageHeader header;
    uint8_t segment_table[256]; // page_segments_num in len
    uint32_t data_len;
    uint8_t data[256 * 256];

    ...
};
```

`PageHeader`:

```
struct __attribute__((packed)) PageHeader {
    char capture_pattern[4]; // should be "OggS"
    uint8_t stream_structure_version; // should be 0
    uint8_t header_type_flag; // 0x1: continued, 0x2: first (bos), 0x4: last (eos)
    int64_t absolute_granule_pos; // end PCM sample position of the last packet completed on that page
    uint32_t stream_serial_num;
    uint32_t page_sequence_num;
    uint32_t page_crc_checksum;
    uint8_t page_segments_num;
};
```

Maybe `__attribute__((packed))` confuses GDB somehow?
Even when I explicitly do this

```
Page* dummy = &buffer_page_;
```

inside some `Page` member function, it also does not show the content of this `dummy` ptr (it's the same address as `this`, because `buffer_page_` starts at zero offset from `this`).

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21254074/how-to-solve-qt-creators-variable-not-accessible-behavior) is related, although I think it is not about `this` (some own `struct`/`class`) but instead about standard types (`std::string` or so). Also, all the given solutions do not have an effect, or do not apply. E.g. "Load system GDB pretty printers" was already disabled.

Comment: Please specify compiler / debugger versions and build options used.

Comment: Is the same set of options used to compiler `OggReader` code? I mean it does not come from some static library pre-build  with different options?

Comment: Yes (the project itself is called OggReader).

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that in optimized builds, you can have some variables that are optimized away or only available in registers. In these cases, there is no way for the debuggers to get the values and you would see these `<not accessible>` or `<optimized away>`.

Lower the optimization level, and you will start seeing more of these variables (at the cost of reduced speed).

It seems here that there is also no default display of non-standard types. `char*` are displayed, because it's a C-style string, so there would be a proper display for them. Just like VS has natvis files, QtCreator support [helpers](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-debugging-helpers.html), Python files that can be used to display just what you need.

If you just want to get the contant of a struct when you only have a pointer, you can also do: `const auto& v = *this;`.

Comment: You can try then by explicitly storing `this` in another variable, as it will not get optimized away. Perhaps even get a pointer on it to for it to be in memory and not in a register.

Comment: I would like to not modify the code just to work around the debugger. Is there no compiler setting to really disable all optimizations?

Comment: It's not an optimization, the compiler doesn't have to have `this` in a memory location (depends on calling conventions IIRC).

Comment: Despite, I'm also not sure if this is really the problem here. I don't really know whether the variable is really optimized away here (any way to check this?). Maybe this is just some bug in Qt creator and/or GDB?

Comment: But it shows a memory location (the pointer address). What is this value then? (Btw, instead of answering me here in the comments, maybe you can extend your answer itself by this information.)

Comment: I tried that now, storing `this` in another variable, but also in that case, I cannot view it.

Comment: I will edit the answer once we have a working case for you ;) What do you mean by 2it shows a memory location"? What is "it" and what's the memory location?

Comment: "[Qt creator / GDB] shows a memory location [for `this`]". You can see the memory location in the screenshot in my question. When I make another copy of it (`OggReader* dump_copy = this;`), then `dump_copy` points to the same memory location.

Comment: In that case try instead `const auto& v=*this;`.

Comment: Also updated the answer with debugging helpers from qtcreator which may be something you want to explore.

Comment: I tried with `const auto& v=*this;` and the debugger shows  `<optimized out>` for `v` (which is a bit unexpected, as I have `-O0`).

Comment: I also tried `const volatile auto v=*this;` (i.e. a copy), and for this `v`, it again shows `<not accessible>`. I tend to think that this is a bug/problem in GDB. But instead of randomly trying around, is there not a way to understand the failure more systematically?

Comment: That's very odd, they should not be optimized away indeed. Perhaps a bug in gdb. Did you try a newer version?